# Linux Mint 18.2, Krita window missing maximize button and can't resize vertically

Tags: linux, linux-mint, window, title-bar, krita

I'm brand new to Linux, just installed Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon (Sonya) on my Dell Latitude XT2 laptop.

For every problem I encountered exploring this strange new OS, I managed to find solutions. However, this seemingly simple one I can't...

The only solutions I find don't solve the problem: use <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, or even <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. They allow me to move the Krita window around, but it is still far too large vertically. I can resize it left and right, but for some reason it doesn't allow me to resize it vertically past a certain point. It can only stay at the ranges between too long and even longer.

Also, Krita's window is missing the Maximize button for some reason...

[image: Krita, no maximize button in title bar]

Here I’ve moved it upwards and resized horizontally,
but I can’t resize it vertically:
[image: Moved upwards and resized, but can't resize upwards]

Any solution or shortcut I don't know? I saw one thread suggested to log out then back in. I haven't tested it yet but I wouldn't want to do that every time I may encounter this issue anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is ridiculously easy to fix. I feel so stupid and just want to delete my question altogether, but I figure someone else may run into this issue one day so I'll leave it.

In Krita, resize the tool panel.

That's it. Now the window has its maximize button back, and it can be resized smaller vertically again.

[image: Tool panel resized to two columns, maximize button returns]

Ugh...

Comment: Also, for those who are curious, logging out then in doesn't work in this case. May work if you encounter a similar problem in a different program, though.

Comment: Didn't help for me, sadly

Comment: @piegames Oh, that's too bad... Besides the toolbox, did you try resizing the other panels too, if you have any others displayed? I find this problem only happens to me when my toolbox is too small, especially when I try to squeeze it in between a bunch of other panels. Also since then, I replaced my Krita 2.9.7 that came with Mint with an Appimage of 4.0.0 (David Revoy has a good tutorial on how). Works much better overall, and has plenty of new features!